Adding common words or public dictionaries to Mathematica's spell check?
Is there an update to this:Stack Exchange 242114?
(That post is a couple years old and has a response from the WRI tech support that the following is impossible and they requested this as a feature)
I find that the default dictionary is missing many common words (e.g."crystals"), and would be burdensome to add common words one at a time.
Can one add other public domain dictionaries?
I could edit FileName[{$UserBaseDirectory, "Paclets", "Repository",    "SpellingData-1.0.13", "SpellingDictionaries"}] by hand, but I don't know what the format is.
It is full of lines like:
crystallization/2 1
crystallize/6 1
crystallographer/10 1
crystallographic
crystallography 1
crystal 1
but I don't know what the syntax means

Does this answer your question? Adding spelling dictionary to Mathematica

@creidhne, No. That’s the post I refer to at the beginning of my message.

I’m seeing votes to close this post because it has already been answered. My post refers to a previous post stating there was no solution several years ago—and my post contains more information.  I believe the votes to close are too hasty.

@CraigCarter - it's still the same question though

@JasonB. It seems a different question since it asks explicitly for the dictionary syntax.

Does this meet your needs?

@Alan, that would allow addition one at a time—which would be a hassle.  I think the ideal solution would be merge with a public spelling dictionary like the ones that are used by ispell or aspell. So, I’m still looking for an answer—or at least a an update on WRI’s tech support answer from several years ago.

The documentation near the bottom shows how to add a list of words programmatically. So you should be able to easily add any aspell list.
